# Trying to setup kiosk server - start firefox from command line without creating new tab

Tags: php, ubuntu, firefox, command-line, kiosk

I'm trying to create a kiosk environment with a mini pc and iPad. I have Ubuntu installed and I'm using the mKiosk Firefox add-on. On boot up, it auto logs in and opens Firefox full screen with the specified page. This part is working fine

Here's where it gets complicated. The box is also setup with PHP and MySQL. I want to call a PHP script from the iPad and have a different page displayed. That's all fine, except that when I call "firefox {url}" from the command line, I get the page in a new tab. It doesn't switch to that tab, so you end up still looking at the first one in full screen. If I CTRL-Tab, I can see that the other tab has opened. It's just not the active one.

Is there any way I can get it to always open pages in the first tab? Alternatively, can I force it to switch active tabs from the command line? Is there a way I can remove a tab programmatically or clear all tabs?

Thanks.

Comment: can you close ff (from the command line), before calling it again with the url?

Comment: I thought of that, but haven't yet figured out how to stop ff from the command line. The kill command would always work, but the logged in user won't have that kind of access level.

Comment: @nogad, actually `killall firefox` worked. There is a bit of a flicker, but not too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. For starters, the mKiosk add-on was changing some of the config settings and locking them. I removed it and went with r-kiosk instead. Then I went to `about:config` in Firefox and did a search for `browser.link`. The two settings listed below are the key to getting the page to open in the same tab. If they're both set to 3, as mkiosk sets them, then all pages open in a new tab. They need to be set to 1 and 0.

```
browser.link.open_newwindow = 1
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction = 0
```

[image]